# tomcat debug cannot find local variables

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, spring-boot

When I use spring boot startup to debug my application, it will display local variables.
But when I use tomcat to debug it, it will only display global variables and method signatures.
I tried to install latest jdk8 and rebuild project, but it didn't work.

When I use spring boot debug mode, the application will restart if I change the class and it will take a lot of time. But tomcat won't restart, this saves me a lot of time.

Update:

[image: tomcat debug]

[image: spring boot debug]

Comment: How are you debugging? What do you mean by "local" variables?

Comment: @Andres I added 2 images, can you help me to solve this problem.Thank you.